# Subversion gets a snapshot of files for a point in time from the past

Tags: svn

Is there a way using Subversion to get snapshot of the files for a particular point in time?

For example, I want to recreate a build based on how the repository looked at an exact point in time from the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `svn checkout URL -r TIME`, e.g.:

```
svn checkout http://server/repos/project/trunk -r {"2010-04-01 09:37:00"}
```

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `svn log` to find the revision that corresponds to the point in time, then `svn co -r revision` to check out that revision.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, if you follow the [ITIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL) and the change management procedure, then you should have tags that correspond with the release history of your application from the SVN repository over a period of time.

All you have to do is check out the code based upon a specific tag and that tag will be representative of how your application looked at a specific moment in time.

The repository can look like many things over a period of time as there could many different developers working on many different projects. Tags allow you centralise your efforts to more concentrated areas of your repository.

I hope this provides you with an insight into basic management.

In **essence**, use tags or the revision numbers that SVN provides or the SVN log if you don't have this documented.